# how to paginate UIScrollView with different page sizes?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to do a horizontal **scroll of UILabels with different widths**.

I've already put all labels next to each other inside the UIScrollView, but since the page scrolling, bouncing and snapping is done in **scrollview.frame.width** "steps", i cannot set it to work as I'd wish.

Can this be done? Thank you so much :)

Answer (score -1):

What happens if you set the size of your width property to be the width of the next label? Something like (in your scroll view delegate) :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    // Get the label that's going to slide into view
    UIView *label = [self getCurrentLabel];

    // Get it's width
    float width = [label frame].size.width;

    // Set our size
    CGRect frame = [scrollView frame];
    frame.size.width = width;
    [scrollView setFrame:frame];
}
```

PS I've not tried this so it might just fail horribly!

Comment: This can't work for many reasons. First you don't know which label will slide into view. The scrollview can scroll left or right. Second the position of label won't probably be just width * labelWhichWillSlideIn.

Comment: Of course you know which label is next - you just have an array of labels and a currentLabel index. And you keep track of which way the scrolling is going with the currentOffset property. and you should already positioned your labels in viewWillAppear. The question just says you the labels are different widths, not that you have nio idea what those withs are!